# Warping an image to another plane

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I have an image in the form of Mat. I am using opencv c++.
I want to warp this image to another plane. I have divided the original image in a 15x15 mesh. All the mesh points are considered as the original vertices. I am doing some operations and getting the target vertices in the new plane. All the original mesh vertices have a corresponding target vertices in the new plane. How do I warp the image to the new plane based on the target vertices and the original vertices.

I was thinking of doing this -> taking each quad in the original and new plane and find the homography between them. Now somehow warp each quad to the new plane but I am not sure how to do that. Can someone suggest me on how to do this or some other better method to do this?

Comment: Is this a one-time thing, or something that has to happen often in an application?

Comment: It will happen multiple times

Comment: could you show examples (pictures)? what type of warp do you need, affine, perspective, linearly interpolated mesh?

Answer (score 0):

Compute Homography for each grid and compute a map. map(x0, y0) = x1, y1. a position (x0, y0) on the target plane is mapped to (x1, y1) on the source plane. i.e. [ax1 ay1 a]T = H [x0, y0, 1]T

Then use `cv::remap`